# why would axios.get not run .then or .catch code?

Tags: javascript, axios

first time using axios in the browser. calling axios.get.  The web service being called runs. But the web service is sending a json formatted response that is not received.  I put a breakpoint in the .then and .catch code and it does not break.

I am converting from $.ajax. How to get the response data?

```js
function prugAdm_upd( key, colName, colvlu, compFunc )
{
  var errmsg = '' ;
  var libl = 'couri7 aplusb1fcc' ;

  axios.get('../../common/json_CallProcReturnEmpty.php', {
    params:  {proc:'prugadm_actn',libl:libl,
    outParm1:errmsg, parm2:'UPD', parm3:key, parm4:colName, parm5:colvlu, debug:'Y'}

  })
  .then(function (response)
  {
    var data    = JSON.parse(response) ;
    var errmsg  = data.outParm1 ;
    if ( typeof(compFunc) != 'undefined')
    {
      compFunc( errmsg ) ;
    }
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error... " + error);
  });
}
```

here is the $.ajax code that I am replacing.

```js
function prugAdm_updOld( key, colName, colvlu, compFunc )
{
  var errmsg = '' ;
  var libl = 'couri7 aplusb1fcc' ;

  $.ajax(
    {
      type:  'GET',
      url:   "../../common/json_CallProcReturnEmpty.php",
      data:  {proc:'prugadm_actn',libl:libl,
              outParm1:errmsg, parm2:'UPD', parm3:key, parm4:colName, parm5:colvlu, debug:'N'},
      cache: false,
      success: function(text)
      {
        var data    = JSON.parse(text) ;
        var errmsg  = data.outParm1 ;
        if ( typeof(compFunc) != 'undefined')
        {
          compFunc( errmsg ) ;
        }
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
      {
          console.log("Error... " + textStatus + "        " + errorThrown);
      },
      dataType: 'text'
  });
}
```

Comment: How did you confirm _being sent but not received_?

Comment: I can see the data being received on the server.

The problem I am having is not axios. Just replaced other $.ajax code and everything works as expected.

Problem I am having is when I call this web service using $.ajax the chrome browser hangs. The code breaks on the $.ajax error method. But I cannot display any variables. Press F8 to continue and the browser hangs until I press F12 to exit developer tools.

Comment: Wait...what? Question is about axios but now question is about jQuery? I confuse easily...can you explain which topic your question is about please: 1. axios.get 2. $.ajax 3. web service

Comment: Having problems when calling both $.ajax and axios. Then web service runs, but on return the $.ajax code hangs the browser.  The axios version does not call the .then or .catch code.

Happens with both firefox and chrome. Hard to debug since I cannot get any breakpoints working after the $.ajax or axios.get calls.

Comment: What is in the network panel of dev tools showing what comes back from the server?

Comment: the XHR tab?  very interesting.   I do not see anything when my problem code runs.  But do see entries when I call $.ajax or axios from working parts of my code.  Figure I will rework the code to use XMLHttpRequest to see if that makes a difference.   Thank you.

Comment: You should try the fetch API, it is much simpler to use and works as it is built into the browser: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: just to clear up the cause of this error.  I had a <button> within a <form>. The button click handler was running $.ajax to call up to the server to do an update. Then in the callback proc, call up to the server to do another update.  But since the <button> did not have type="button" the form was being submitted on the button click. So I was running code that depended on a callback, but the form was also being submitted. Meaning I had code sitting at a break point, but then the submitted form was refreshing the page.